# Sesame And RDF4J Custom Server Data Location

Tags: sesame, openrdf, rdf4j

I have a Tomcat instance running an openrdf-sesame environment. By default the location of my openrdf-sesame database configuration and data is at %APPDATA%\aduna. I am trying to change where this data saves to something custom like C:\aduna. I have looked at documentation online, but it does not specify if this is defined in a configuration file somewhere or if it is an hard coded location. I also saw that RDF4J is a new replacement for openrdf-sesame? I wouldn't mind upgrading if I could achieve the result of specifying where to save my data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenRDF Sesame is no longer maintained, it has been succeeded by the [Eclipse RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org/) project. There is a [migration guide](http://docs.rdf4j.org/migration/) available to help you figure out what to do when updating your project.

Although the Sesame project is no longer maintained, a [documentation archive](http://archive.rdf4j.org/) is available, and of course a lot of the [RDF4J documentation](http://docs.rdf4j.org/) also applies to Sesame, albeit with slightly different package names.

As for your specific question: the directory Sesame Server uses is determined by the system property `info.aduna.platform.appdata.basedir`. Set this property (at JVM startup, using the `-D` flag) to the desired location. See the archived documentation about [application directory configuration](http://archive.rdf4j.org/users/ch07.html) for more details. As an aside: note that in RDF4J this property has been renamed (to `org.eclipse.rdf4j.appdata.basedir`), so if you upgrade to RDF4J, be sure to change this.

Comment: Perfect! I should probably consider upgrading too. Thank you